# Facing an error when working with monero.fail (monero node tracker)

Tags: monerod, daemon, synchronization, development, monerod-commands

https://monero.fail/
This is the monero node tracker.

https://github.com/lalanza808/monero.fail
After following the steps to make the project work, I am facing an attribute error where the function `last_height` is getting a null value. How can I solve this error? Is the project already connected to the monero network or do I have to do it myself? Nowhere in the code can I find where the connection is made to the monero network. Adding some screenshots for reference [image]

Comment: Looking at the config shows it expects to have a monero node already running on localhost. Have you done this bit?

Comment: No i haven't. Thats the doubt i have, does monerod has to be fully synced, is that necessary ?

Comment: also where is this config which tells that monero node is needed on localhost ?

Comment: https://github.com/lalanza808/monero.fail/blob/3555e23eb8ba589da64adba72f1be639ad1cbbef/xmrnodes/config.example.py#L7-L8
 and yes, it would need to be synced (a node not synced is basically useless).

Comment: Thank you so much, i am going to try doing that today

Answer (score 1):

> How can I solve this error? Is the project already connected to the monero network or do I have to do it myself?

You need to run a node (or use a public one).

> Nowhere in the code can I find where the connection is made to the monero network.

You set the node address and port in your configuration file (see the example in the repository [config.example.py](https://github.com/lalanza808/monero.fail/blob/3555e23eb8ba589da64adba72f1be639ad1cbbef/xmrnodes/config.example.py#L7-L8)).